# Regex to get value of JSON in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, regex

I'm trying to get the value of a json that is stored like a string.

I thought about taking the values ​​as follows:

```
(: ") (value) (" [,}])
```

This is an example of what I want to do, get the value between the characteres:

`:"` and `",` or `"}`

Ex:

```
'{\"key1\":\"any text\",\"key2\":\"any text\"}'
```

Get: `any text`

I'm having trouble when creating the regex, and I would like to know if someone could explain how to make this regex for mysql columns.

OBS: the version of mysql is 5.6 and do not support json column

Comment: You really should upgrade if you need to work with JSON data. Besides, [MySQL 5.6 is past its end-of-life](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql), so it's time to upgrade even if you weren't working with JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you were on the right track. The value will be in the first capture group for each match:

`/:\\"(.*?)\\"/g`

Breakdown:

- `:\\"` matches :\"
- `(.*?)` group of all characters until the first instance of the character that immediately follows...
- `\\"` matchs \"